# Define complex type in ServiceStack Swagger-UI

Tags: servicestack, swagger

I'm trying to achieve something like this
http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/#!/store/placeOrder_post_2
I want to define custom DataType to use it in `DataType` parameter of `ServiceStack.ServiceHost.ApiMember` attribute so that ServiceStack generates Model and Model Schema sections for me, like in the above URL.

How can I achieve this?